# Matlab: gradient of a scalar field

Tags: matlab, vector, gradient, scalar

I have a data in the following format.

```
x y density
. .   .
. .   .
. .   .
```

Here, `density` is the scalar. How to perform gradient on this dataset? I tried the `gradient` operator in Matlab. However, it returns only a scalar.

Note: Both `x` and `y` are uniformly spaced with unit spacing. The boundary points end as floating point numbers, as it is clipped data.

Comment: Is your data uniformly spaced?

Comment: Yes. It is uniformly spaced. Both `x` and `y` spacing are of 1.

Comment: Do X and Y start at `1` as well?

Comment: @SathishKrishnan What have you tried exactly? `gradient` is the right way to go, but you need to have a look at the output arguments: you need two to get a vector output.

Comment: @Suever: No. Note: The boundary points end as floating point numbers, as it is clipped data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the rows of your data so that the data points can be reshaped into a 2D matrix. You can then compute the gradient of *that*.

```
% Sort so that we get the density into column-major ordering
[~, inds] = sortrows(data(:,[1 2]));

% Reshape the density data so it's [numel(Y) x numel(X)]
density = reshape(data(inds,3), numel(unique(data(:,2))), numel(unique(data(:,1))));

% Compute the X and Y gradients
[FX, FY] = gradient(density);
```

Comment: One issue. I notice there are some boundary points, which are `floats`, as the plane is clipped. Is it possible to include them? Otherwise, I will make script to exclude those points and try your solution.

Comment: @SathishKrishnan This should handle floats just fine. Are you saying that they *aren't* equally spaced at the boundary?

Comment: @SathishKrishnan Yes so that's probably your best bet as the gradient at the boundary is going to be poorly defined anyhow.

Comment: Further, I am getting error regarding `reshape` operation. `Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change`

Comment: @SathishKrishnan Are you sure you have equally spaced data then? Try plotting your x and y points with `plot(data(:,1), data(:,2), 'o')` to make sure. That error implies that you don't have a complete grid of x and y points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121945/discussion-between-sathish-krishnan-and-suever).